# Nested If Else Question Not Working in Dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm working with a column in a dataframe of numeric data called "L_D" which has a range of values from 0.6-1.9. I'm trying to create a new column that categorizes the range in 3 ranges: "high" for L_D>1.4, "low" for L_D<0.9, or "medium".

```
#add L/D grouping to CompStrngth, <0.9=Low aspect ratio; >1.4=High Aspect Ratio, else = other raio
ifelse(CompStrngthData$L_D > 1.4, CompStrngthData$L_D_group <- "high",
   ifelse(CompStrngthData$L_D > 0.9, CompStrngthData$L_D_group <- "medium",
        CompStrngthData$L_D_group <- "low" )
)
```

When I run this code, it produces the desired result in the console. But when I open up the dataframe, it produces a column filled with "low".

Because of that I found the cut function and it works great with the desired results

```
CompStrngthData$L_D_group <- cut(CompStrngthData$L_D, breaks = c(-Inf,0.9,1.4,Inf), labels = c("low", "medium", "high"))
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake I'm overlooking with the dataframe or if else function, just looking to understand my error.

Comment: I've never seen a situation where assignment within the `yes=` or `no=` arguments of `ifelse` was a reasonable thing to do. While it is *syntactically legal* to do so, it's always (imo) been more confusing than not, so like @akrun's answer, I always keep assignments *outside* of `ifelse` (nested or otherwise).

Comment: Can you dput your data to help reproduce and troubleshoot the issue you are running into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be with the assignment inside the `ifelse`, instead, take it outside

```
CompStrngthData$L_D_group <- ifelse(CompStrngthData$L_D > 1.4,  "high",
    ifelse(CompStrngthData$L_D > 0.9, "medium",
    "low" )
         )
```

Comment: That is it! Knew it was something simple like that. Though, I much prefer the cut function, especially if I was working with more groupings.